# Laravel middleware 'api' MethodNotAllowedHttpException

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5

in my /routes/api.php next code

```
Route::middleware('api')->group(function(){

    Route::get('/prepare/', 'CompgenApiController@prepareDefault');

    Route::get('/replace/', 'CompgenApiController@replaceImage');

    Route::get('/collage/', 'CompgenApiController@collage');

    Route::get('/generate/', 'CompgenApiController@generate');

    Route::post('/upload/', 'CompgenApiController@userUpload');

});
```

all get-methods work fine but when i try use Route::post i got an error

> "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpException"

this is the request code

```
    uploadFile(){

        axios.post('/api/upload/',{

            src: 'test'

        }).then(function (result) {
               console.log(result);
            });


    }
```

also in my app/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php i have

```
    protected $except = [
    '/api/upload/'
];
```

Comment: Can you also post the code you use to send a form / request to that route?

Comment: http://joxi.ru/xAeLxPpSpk8Gy2

Comment: Can you check that your request actually fails at `POST` call?

Comment: yea, if i change POST to GET and try with postman i got

http://joxi.ru/Vm66DpgFDaWaxm

Comment: try without `Route::middleware('api')->group(function(){` ?

Comment: then page not found

Answer (score 1):

what you have done is applied an `api` middleware on routes. why don't you try to update your code like this and then the routes defined inside your controller will be accepted with an `api/` prefix.

```
Route::group([
    'prefix'        => 'api',
    'middleware'    => ['auth.api']
], function () {
    //define routes here
});
```

Comment: Aren't all routes inside of `api.php` file prefixed with `api` by default?

Comment: can't say for sure. but in my case this works perfectly well, even within the `api.php`. do you have some doc link? @NikolaGavric

Comment: then why the prefix api is automatically added to all GET requests?

Comment: I didn't you @Viktor, after changing your code to this does your javascript code working
?

Comment: > Routes defined in the routes/api.php file are nested within a route group by the  RouteServiceProvider. Within this group, the /api URI prefix is automatically applied so you do not need to manually apply it to every route in the file. https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/routing#basic-routing @ShobiPP

Comment: @ShobiPP no, it's doens't